# Can I finish 2 activities using backpress

Tags: android, android-activity

I call B Activity on A Activity. But B Activity background is transparent. So I can't use INTENT_FLAG. A activity have to remain.

So!

When I press back button How to finish 2 Activities together? 
Not Using INTENT_FLAG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to start your second activity for result from the first activity as following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Then, in your `SecondActivity` override `onBackPressed`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

And in your `FirstActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        finish();
    }
}
```